# How to consume multiple messages in parallel and detect when all execution have completed?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to send multiple messages that will traverse the same route asynchronously and be able to know when all processing have completed.

Since I need to know when each route has terminated, I thought about using
[`ProducerTemplate#asyncRequestBody`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.html#asyncRequestBody(org.apache.camel.Endpoint,%20java.lang.Object)) which use *InOut* pattern so that calling `get` on the [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object returned will block until the route has terminated.

So far so good, each request are sent asynchronously to the route, and looping over all Future calling get method will block until all
my routes have completed.

The problem is that, while the requests are sent asynchronously, I want them to be also consumed in parallel.

For example, consider P being the `ProducerTemplate`, R<sub>n</sub> beeing requests and E<sub>n</sub> being endpoints - what I want is :

```
  ->   R0 -> from(E1).to(E2).to(E3) : done.
 /
P ->   R1 -> from(E1).to(E2).to(E3) : done.
 \  
  ->   R2 -> from(E1).to(E2).to(E3) : done.

        ^__ Requests consumed in parallel.
```

After a few research, I stumbled onto [Competing Consumers](http://camel.apache.org/competing-consumers.html) which parallelize execution adding more consumers.

However, since there is multiple executions at the same time, this slow down the execution of each route which causes some [`ExchangeTimedOutException`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ExchangeTimedOutException.html) :

```
The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID...
```

Not a surprise, as I am sending an *InOut* request. But actually, I don't really care of the response, I use it only to know 
when my route has terminated. I would use an *InOnly* ([`ProducerTemplate#asyncSendBody`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.html#asyncSendBody(org.apache.camel.Endpoint,%20java.lang.Object))), but calling `Future#get` would not block until
the entire task is completed.

Is there another alternative to send requests asynchronously and detect when they have all completed?

Note that changing the timeout is not an option in my case.

Comment: Perhaps giving your requests an id and have the consumers send a message to your producer whenever a requests is processed including that id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct is to recommend using [NotifyBuilder](https://camel.apache.org/notifybuilder.html) to track the processing, more specifically using the `whenBodiesDone` to target specific bodies.

**EDIT:**

Here's a trivial implementation but it does demonstrate a point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Component
  public static class ParallelProcessingRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
      from("seda:test?concurrentConsumers=5")
          .routeId("parallel")
          .log("Received ${body}, processing")
          .delay(5000)
          .log("Processed ${body}")
          .stop();

      from("timer:testStarter?delay=3000&period=300000")
          .routeId("test timer")
          .process(exchange -> {
            // messages we want to track
            List<Integer> toSend = IntStream.range(0, 5).boxed().collect(toList());

            NotifyBuilder builder = new NotifyBuilder(getContext())
                .fromRoute("parallel")
                .filter(e -> toSend.contains(e.getIn().getBody(Integer.class)))
                .whenDone(toSend.size())
                .create();

            ProducerTemplate template = getContext().createProducerTemplate();

            // messages we do not want to track
            IntStream.range(10, 15)
                .forEach(body -> template.sendBody("seda:test", body)); 

            toSend.forEach(body -> template.sendBody("seda:test", body)); 

            exchange.getIn().setBody(builder.matches(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
          })
          .log("Matched? ${body}");
    }
  }
}
```

And here's a sample of the logs:

```
2016-08-06 11:45:03.861  INFO 27410 --- [1 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Received 10, processing
2016-08-06 11:45:03.861  INFO 27410 --- [5 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Received 11, processing
2016-08-06 11:45:03.864  INFO 27410 --- [2 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Received 12, processing
2016-08-06 11:45:03.865  INFO 27410 --- [4 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Received 13, processing
2016-08-06 11:45:03.866  INFO 27410 --- [3 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Received 14, processing
2016-08-06 11:45:08.867  INFO 27410 --- [1 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Processed 10
2016-08-06 11:45:08.867  INFO 27410 --- [3 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Processed 14
2016-08-06 11:45:08.867  INFO 27410 --- [4 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Processed 13
2016-08-06 11:45:08.868  INFO 27410 --- [2 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Processed 12
2016-08-06 11:45:08.868  INFO 27410 --- [5 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Processed 11
2016-08-06 11:45:08.870  INFO 27410 --- [1 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Received 0, processing
2016-08-06 11:45:08.872  INFO 27410 --- [4 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Received 2, processing
2016-08-06 11:45:08.872  INFO 27410 --- [3 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Received 1, processing
2016-08-06 11:45:08.872  INFO 27410 --- [2 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Received 3, processing
2016-08-06 11:45:08.872  INFO 27410 --- [5 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Received 4, processing
2016-08-06 11:45:13.876  INFO 27410 --- [1 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Processed 0
2016-08-06 11:45:13.876  INFO 27410 --- [3 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Processed 1
2016-08-06 11:45:13.876  INFO 27410 --- [4 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Processed 2
2016-08-06 11:45:13.876  INFO 27410 --- [5 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Processed 4
2016-08-06 11:45:13.876  INFO 27410 --- [2 - seda://test] parallel                                 : Processed 3
2016-08-06 11:45:13.877  INFO 27410 --- [r://testStarter] test timer                               : Matched? true
```

You'll notice how the `NotifyBuilder` returned the result as soon as the results matched.

Comment: Interesting, so if I understand right : when done will send the Object you passed to the builder to a `:confirm` endpoint ? Then I can wait using `NotifyBuilder#matches` and check if I have all my messages at `:endpoint`. Am-I right ?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's implemented - I've always assumed it's using interceptors -  but you shouldn't care about that. Your only concern should be building the correct condition and choosing a reasonable wait interval and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm on phone at the moment, but don't worry I'll check the answer soon and give feedback when I'm on computer.

Comment: Had any luck with `NotifyBuilder`?

Comment: Actually my requirements changed since few days so I did not ended using this, but running your demo I'm quite sure it would have solved my issue. Your answer solve my question. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score -1):

If you know each batch of messages you are consuming has X messages in them you can use an [aggregator](https://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html) at the end of your parallel processing. For your example, each group of message would have it's own unique header tag that will be picked up by the aggregator. After all the messages have been processes and all the messages have ended up at the aggregator you can aggregate the messages to whatever format you want and return them.